# Adding a mask with CALayers

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, quartz-graphics

I seem to be having difficulties adding a mask via CALayers. I'm simply trying to mask a UIImageView. Here's my code:

```
 CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
 UIImage *mask = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"];
 maskLayer.contents = mask;

UIImageView *viewToMask = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
viewToMask.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.png"];
viewToMask.layer.mask = maskLayer;
[self.view addSubview:viewToMask];
```

Mask.png is black with a transparent circle punched through it (is this correct way to mask?). I'm not sure where this is failing, perhaps at `maskLayer.contents` since its supposed to be a `CGImageRef` but I get errors when I set it as `mask.CGImage`, or through a local variable `CGImageRef = mask.CGImage`. Anyway, the way its set now doesn't give errors, so I hope its fine.

Does anyone know what's going on, or how to properly set masks with CALayers? Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try

```
maskLayer.contents = (id)mask.CGImage;
```

Yes, the cast sucks, but it's necessary.

---

I think you'll also need to say

```
maskLayer.bounds = (CGRect){CGPointZero, mask.size};
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help on the original question, I was trying to follow through with your suggestions. Anyhow, that doesn't seem to do the trick either. I don't see any masks or my viewToMask for that matter.

Comment: @user339946: You probably need to define the `bounds` of `maskLayer`.

Comment: Frame worked well for me too. Love how little code is required to apply a mask... brilliant. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 13):

try this:

```
CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
UIImage *mask = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"];
maskLayer.contents = (id)mask.CGImage;
//  maskLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter;
maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,1024,768);

UIImageView *viewToMask = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
viewToMask.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.png"];
viewToMask.layer.mask = maskLayer;
[self.view addSubview:viewToMask];
```

you also need to set mask frame