# Draw path ontop of UIImageView - Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, quartz-2d

I have some circles, labels and buttons in a UIView. I also have an imageView that should show a background picture. So I want the circles (paths) to be on top of the imageView. The label and buttons are on top of the imageview since I arranged them so in the IB. But how should I do to bring the paths to the front??

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about masking. You can use CALayer.mask for this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595479/adding-a-mask-with-calayers

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices, I believe:

1. Subclass `UIImageView` and support subviews.  You then add a transparent `UIView` subclass as the subview and draw the paths/whatever in this subview.  Your subclassed `UIImageView` needs to manage the auto-resizing of this "path subview", which is as simple as setting its frame to match the imageviews, however knowing which methods to override could be tricky.
2. Update the image displayed in the background image of the imageview to composite the paths/whatever over the image.

Comment: What did you mean with the 2nd option?

Comment: @JimmyYXA Basically changing the image to include the background original and the path.

Comment: how do I do that then?